# Pass column of eigen matrix as argument to function that index it

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to pass a column of a matrix to a function and index that column in the function:

```
//main.cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

void foo(VectorXd const & columnOfMatrix) {
   for(int i=0; i<columnOfMatrix.rows(); ++i)
      columnOfMatrix(i); //How can I do this?
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Ones(5,5);
   foo(A);
}
```

I have tried using "Eigen::Ref < Eigen::MatrixXd const> &" but this type does not seem to support indexing.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. If I change the type of `columnOfMatrix` to `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd const> const&` and call the function as `foo(A.col(3))`, the program works for me.